# Sub line gives compile error: variable not defined

Tags: compilation

Upon trying to run my code I get the error `"compile error: variable not defined"` and it highlights my Sub line. Here is the code for reference.

```
Sub RI_Processing()
    Dim i As Single
    Dim Output() As Single 'Define this dynamic array for the solver output

Process the DMSO data
    For i = 1 To 45 Step 1
        Workbooks("Calibration Range 1 Normalized Profiles.xlsx").Activate
        RawData.Range("C10:C649") = Sheet1.Columns("i").Values
        SolverOk SetCell:="$E$7", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$2:$B$4", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve
        Workbooks("Simulated Fresnel Function.xlsx").Activate
        Output(i, 1) = Sheet1.Range("B4").Values

    Next i

    i = 0

    ' Process the NaCl Data
    For i = 1 To 102 Step 1
        Workbooks("Calibration Range 1 Normalized Profiles.xlsx").Activate
        RawData.Range("C10:C649") = Sheet2.Columns("i").Values
        SolverOk SetCell:="$E$7", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$2:$B$4", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve
        Workbooks("Simulated Fresnel Function.xlsx").Activate
        Output(i, 2) = Sheet1.Range("B4").Values

    Next i

    i = 0

    ' Process the Sucrose data
    For i = 1 To 72 Step 1
        Workbooks("Calibration Range 1 Normalized Profiles.xlsx").Activate
        RawData.Range("C10:C649") = Sheet3.Columns("i").Values 'Copies the data of all 'i' columns to raw data for solver
        SolverOk SetCell:="$E$7", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$2:$B$4", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve 'Run solver
        Workbooks("Simulated Fresnel Function.xlsx").Activate
        Output(i, 3) = Sheet1.Range("B4").Values 'Put solver output to the matrix 'output' in the appropriate columns

    Next i

End Sub
```